# Cursor moving inside input after formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 16 with TypeScript and tailwind.
I'm building an Input which is supposed to store percentage value, so min 0 and max 100. The request is to have it showed with two numbers after the comma.
This is my actual input:

```
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="text-primary text-left px-2 border-b border-[#E0E0E0] w-3/4">
        <input
          class="text-3xl w-full"
          type="number"
          matInput
          placeholder="0.00 %"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="pointsEstimatedUtilization"
          (ngModelChange)="onEstimatedUtilizationInputChange()"
          oninput="this.value = Math.min(this.value, 100).toFixed(2)"
        />
      </span>
      <span class="w-1/4 flex justify-center items-center text-xl">%</span>
    </div>
```

What happens is that as default is displayed 0 (it's fine for me), if I write for example a '1' before the 0, it gets correctly formatted as 10,00, but the problem is that the cursor went to the end of the input, so just after the two zeros.
For example, if I'll have to write for instance 50, straight after I press 5 the cursor goes to the end, leaving the input something like 5,00 and without allowing me to write anymore (because there is the toFixed(2), because after the cursor moved it was like I was adding the 0 at the end like 5,000)

Is there a way to keep the cursor where it is and still getting it formatted?

Comment: I don't think you should be updating the input's actual `value`, but rather create a custom component, maybe one that overlays the input to display what you actually want.

Comment: I have to agree with @NickFelker especially since the `toFixed` returns a string and not a number, so you may have issues with types.

Comment: You are also deliberately making the model out of sync with the value of the input which may cause strange behavior.

Also, using the `oninput` is not the "Angular" way of handling events. Using `(input)` would be the more "Angular" way. That would also give you access to the `event$` which has a reference to the element and you could get rid of the `this`, which could confuse other angular developers.